# Add extra object which contains each JSON data in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am converting csv data to json data, after converting data, I want to add one extra row which contain each json data. Please see the picture below.

#code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
jsonArray = []
  
#read csv file
with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
    #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

    #convert each csv row into python dict
    for row in csvReader: 
        #add this python dict to json array
        jsonArray.append(row)

#convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
 with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
    jsonf.write(jsonString)
      
  csvFilePath = r'address.csv'
  jsonFilePath = r'address.json'
  csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I am getting json from csv in this format.
**json from csv**

```
[{
"Full Address": "data1",
"p1": "1",
"p2": "6"  },

{
"Full Address": "data2",
"p1": "1",
"p2": "6"
}]
```

But I want to change json in this format.

**json**

```
 [{
   "fields": {
"Full Address": "data1",
"p1": "1",
"p2": "6"
 }
   },

 {
 "fields": {
"Full Address": "data2",
"p1": "1",
"p2": "6"
 }
 }]
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY83l.png)
[image: Picture]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to niftily wrap each dict row read from the `DictReader` in a `"fields"` key.

Also, removing all of the extra "fluff", your function becomes simply

```
def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding="utf-8") as csvf:
        arr = [{"fields": row} for row in csv.DictReader(csvf)]
    with open(jsonFilePath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonf:
        json.dump(arr, jsonf, indent=4)
```